# Filtering in firebase json data by curl php

Tags: json, rest, curl, firebase

how can I search data by email id "subu@gmail.com"?

firebase data

```
{
    "-K5swDCvGh-fWBC3rvzz": {
        "email": "subu@gmail.com",
        "facebook_id": "123456789",
        "password": "111",
        "source": "facebook",
        "username": "subu"
    },
    "-K5sxFSS4NC8tRRCtN-t": {
        "email": "subu_google@gmail.com",
        "google_id": "987456321",
        "password": "111",
        "source": "google",
        "username": "subu_google"
    }
}
```

my data curl is

```
https://subu.firebaseio.com/users.json
```

my firebase rule is look below

```
{
    "rules": {
        "users": {
          ".indexOn": "email"
        },
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help? If so please mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clean.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the orderBy query string parameter**

```
curl https://subu.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="email"
```

If you need to do further restricting you can use `startAt`, `endAt`, or `equalTo`.

The query below retrieves a user by their email:

```
https://subu.firebaseio.com/users.json?orderBy="email"&equalTo="subu@gmail.com"
```

[Read the section on Filtering Data in the Firebase docs for more information.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-filtering)

Comment: How I can pass two perimeters?